# Nested For - Loops to create multiplication table C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested

I've been trying to overcome this problem for a few hours now and I seem to have one approach to the situation. It seems that the use of selection statements worked in creating the table necessary. Although there are formatting issues.

I'd like to know if there was a way to create the same table 
**using only nested for-loops as mentioned by our professor**.

Are the selection statements necessary or can we implement a system of nested for loops to acquire the same results?

The image below is the required table:

[image: Here is the required table]

---

**But the image below is what I have**:
[image: Here is my result]

Below is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numChoice; ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k <= numChoice; ++k)
            {
                cout << "    " << k;
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << i << " | ";
            for (int j = 1; j <= numChoice; ++j)
            {
                if (j*i <= 9)
                {
                    cout << "   " << j*i << "|";
                }
                else if (j*i > 9 && j*i <= 100)
                {
                    cout << "  " << j*i << "|";
                }
                else if (j*i > 99 && j*i <= 999)
                {
                    cout << " " << j*i << "|";
                }
            }
            cout << "\n";
            for (int k = 0; k <= numChoice; ++k)
            {
                if (k == 0)
                {
                    cout << "-|";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "----|";
                }
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question isnt that clear. Is it about the formatting of the table? You mean the "selection statements" that you use to know what is the number of digits? The are io manipulators that let you format a table: [right](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/right/) and [setw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/).

Comment: You already have *nested for loops* in your code sample, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: @zett42 Main question is -  would I need the selection statements to accomplish this task or is it possible to use only nested for loops for the same results.

Comment: @tobi303 - right I am aware of the setw feature. My main concern is what I mentioned above about the selection statements being necessary or not.

Comment: @FranticCode You do not need to use the selection statements; check out my answer bellow.

Comment: @FranticCode, if you can use a `std::setw` and its sister function, then your code can be modified slightly to [**this**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d3ef93cbce72ec8). Try compiling with a different `Width` in the link, and see the dynamic effect.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Alright so what I'm understanding from all the responses is that I would still need to apply an if else to get the chart printed for that desired output.

Comment: @FranticCode If you dont want any if else, use my code.

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses **no if else constructs**. The formatting can be got by using `setw`, used for setting the width of integers.Following code produces perfect output.

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<iomanip>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   { 
   int i,j;    
   cout<<"     "<<1;//5 space chars

   for(i = 2;i <= 10;++i)
       cout<<"    "<<i;//4 space chars

   cout<<endl;
   cout<<"   ----|";

   for(i = 2;i <= 10;++i)
       cout<<"----|";

   cout<<endl;

   for(i = 1;i <= 10;++i)
   {
       cout<<setw(2)<<i<<"|";

       for(j = 1;j <= 10;++j)
          cout<<setw(4)<<j*i<<"|";

       cout<<endl;
       cout<<" -|----";

       for(j = 2;j <= 9;++j)
          cout<<"|----";

       cout<<"|----|";
       cout<<endl;

   }
   return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Hey thanks this helped a ton! The only issue is it won't go above 10 I'm rewriting it now but the formatting of the lines gets thrown off but thank you still1

Answer (score 0):

@FranticCode. I'm also in the same class as you and was having problems with this homework assignment as well. I still don't understand it, but I figured out how to manipulate Sumeet's code to give us correct format. The ONLY thing I am having a problem with now is adding an empty space AFTER the first multiplication table and before the menu redisplay. I'll share what I have and maybe you can figure it out. Still going to ask the professor to review chapter 5 because I would like to *learn* it rather than just submit the homework.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char userSelection;
    int numForTable;
    int col;
    int row;

do
{
    cout << "MENU" << endl
         << "a) Generate Multiplication Table" << endl
         << "q) Quit the program" << endl
         << "Please make a selection: ";
    cin  >> userSelection;

    if (userSelection == 'a')
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number for your multiplication table: " << endl;
        cin >> numForTable;

        while (numForTable < 1 || numForTable > 10)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a number between 1 & 10." << endl;
            cin >> numForTable;
        }

        cout << "\n"
             << "MULTIPLICATION TABLE: " << numForTable << "'s" << endl
             << "\n"
             << "    " << 1;

        for (col = 2; col <= numForTable; ++col)

            cout << "    " << col;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "   ----|";


        for (col = 2; col <= numForTable; ++col)

            cout << "----|";
            cout << endl;


        for (col = 1; col <= numForTable; ++col)
             {
                 cout << setw(2) << col << "|";

                 for (row = 1; row <= numForTable; ++row)

                     cout << setw(4) << col * row << "|";
                     cout << endl;
                     cout << " -|----";

                 for (row = 2; row <= numForTable - 1; ++row)

                     cout << "|----";
                     cout << "|----|";
                     cout << endl;       
             }
    }

     else if (userSelection != 'q')
     {
         cout << "Invalid Selection\n" << endl;
     }

     else if (userSelection == 'q')
     {
         cout << " You have chosen to quit the program. Thank you for using!" << endl;
     }
}

while (userSelection != 'q');

//system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! is shroyer your prof.? Which class period are you in?

Comment: She is :) and Monday night class. I'm Kevin.  I posted the same question, more or less, and was directed to your post by someone's comment who said we had very similar questions

Answer (score 0):

got curious to see if i could add the lines as easy as i claimed, it took a bit of fiddling, but here's the result (updated code below to also have lines).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int counter;
    int counter2;
    int amount;
    
    cout << " |-----------------------------------------------------------|" << endl; // first line of table.
    
    for(counter=1;counter<11;counter++){            // the 2 for lines create our 2 dimensional table
        for(counter2=1;counter2<11;counter2++){
            
            cout << " | " << setw(3) << counter*counter2; // setw(3) is a function of <iomanip>, 
            //setting minimum width to 3 for numbers.
            
        }
        
        cout << " |" << endl; // this here is being added to the end of each line and starts a new line.
                
        cout << " |-----------------------------------------------------------|" << endl; // this is being inserted between each line, and starts a new line.
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following construct:

```
for (int i=0; i<=numChoice; i++) // display first row of numbers
 cout <<"\t" << i << "\t";
cout << "\n";
for (int i=0; i <=numChoice; i++) {
  cout << i << "\t";
  for (int j=0; j <=numChoice; j++)
    cout << i*j << "\t";
cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use your provided code but it printed mixed results. Thank you anyway.